# Reservation System With Calendar Integration

Tags: looking-for-a-script, open-source, calendar

I am working on a Website for a tour guide. I need an self-hosted online reservation system that supports Paypal payment processing. I also need it to have some sort of iCal/Google Calendar integration.

I have tried searching, but very few services offer calendar integration.

Do you know of anything good, possibly open-source?

Comment: There are many free Calendar pickers, http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline for one. Many more: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/useful-calendar-date-picker-scripts-for-web-developers/

Comment: @ionFish I am looking for a full separate calendar system. Something like you select the tour you want, choose your date, enter your info, an pay. Then the information can be displayed to admins in the admin panel. I have found several, but none have calendar integration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Dont know of any services, specially open source options, but google calendar supports calDav and has an api where if you invested the time you would code it where reservations in your database show up as calendar items on google.   Try searching GitHub for php (or whatever you are comfortable coding in) and the keywords ical, caldav, calendar and see if any open source projects fit the bill.